# Using node js restify and restify-oauth2

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm beginner in developing Web ​​Services, I have a server with node js and module restify, and I want to add authentication using module OAuth2-restify. But as I struggled to prepare a request for get token.I use node restify client for make request.Please somebody can provide me some example. The documentation say

If a valid token is supplied in the Authorization header, req.username is truthy and
The token endpoint, managed entirely by Restify–OAuth2. It generates tokens for a given client ID/client secret/username/password combination.
But how I get a token?? here is the documentacion https://github.com/domenic/restify-oauth2
When I test a sevice width a restify-client I get this error
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Must supply a body."}

```
here is my code:
--------------------------------------Server--------------------------------
   var SERVER_PORT = 8800; 
   var restify = require('restify');
   var server = restify.createServer({
    name: "Example Restify-OAuth2 Client Credentials Server",
    //version: require("../../package.json").version,
    formatters: {
        "application/hal+json": function (req, res, body) {
            return res.formatters["application/json"](req, res, body);
        }
    }
   });

   server.use(restify.authorizationParser());
   server.use(restify.queryParser());
   server.use(restify.bodyParser({ mapParams: false }));
   var restifyOAuth2 = require("restify-oauth2");
   var hooks = require("./hooks");
   restifyOAuth2.cc(server,  { tokenEndpoint:"/token", hooks: hooks });

   //server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));

   var handlers = require('./handlers');
   handlers.setHandlers(server);
   server.listen(SERVER_PORT);
--------------------------------------handlers--------------------------------
   module.exports = {

    setHandlers: function(server) 
      { 
            var restify = require('restify');
            var token=function(req,res,next) {
                          owner=req.body.owner;
                           password=req.password.owner;
                          if(req.username)
                                     res.send({result:"sucess"});

                  }
         server.get("/token",token);

    }
   }
-----------------------------client restify for test services--------------------------------   
   var restify = require('restify');
   var client = restify.createJsonClient({
   url: 'http://localhost:8800',
  version: '*'
});

   client.post('/token', { client_id: 'officialApiClient',client_secret: officialApiClient'},    function(err, req, res, obj) {
  //assert.ifError(err);
  //console.log('%d -> %j', res.statusCode, res.headers);
  console.log('%j', obj);
});
```

Comment: have you figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a POST body to your request with the following parameters:

```
grant_type = client_credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

You have send a POST request to the "token" endpoint using Basic Authentication and as Jordy said add grant_type parameter:

```
POST /oauth/token
Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50SWQ6c2VjcmV0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
grant_type=client_credentials
```